# How to filter for mismatch as well in the list when using the dplyr filter function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of data frames, `outcome_split[[i]]` which has state wise hospital data where there is also a rank column for each data frame.

I want to extract the hospital name and state for the rank matched so I used the below code and got the output.

```
> outcome_rank_filter[[i]] <- outcome_split[[i]] %>% filter(rank==num) %>% select(hospital_name, state)
> head(rankall("heart attack", 20), 10)
                                                      hospital_name state
    1                                D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL
    2                             ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER    AR
    3                           JOHN C LINCOLN DEER VALLEY HOSPITAL    AZ
    4                                         SHERMAN OAKS HOSPITAL    CA
    5                                      SKY RIDGE MEDICAL CENTER    CO
    6                                       MIDSTATE MEDICAL CENTER    CT
    7                                SOUTH FLORIDA BAPTIST HOSPITAL    FL
    8                                 UPSON REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    GA
    9                                       COVENANT MEDICAL CENTER    IA
    10 JESSE BROWN VA MEDICAL CENTER - VA CHICAGO HEALTHCARE SYSTEM    IL
```

But I want 'NA' to inserted where there is no match. As the filter function does a perfect match it is ignoring the results.

I would later pass `outcome_rank_filter[[i]]` as below so it can be collapsed as one dataframe.

```
 output <- do.call(rbind, outcome_rank_filter)
```

I would like the result to be as below where it would return NA for mismatch. I tried merge function but unable to achieve the desired result.

```
**> head(rankall("heart attack", 20), 10)
hospital                                    state
AK <NA>                                       AK
AL D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL             AL
AR ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER          AR
AZ JOHN C LINCOLN DEER VALLEY HOSPITAL        AZ
CA SHERMAN OAKS HOSPITAL                      CA
CO SKY RIDGE MEDICAL CENTER                   CO
CT MIDSTATE MEDICAL CENTER                    CT
DC <NA>                                       DC
DE <NA>                                       DE
FL SOUTH FLORIDA BAPTIST HOSPITAL             FL**
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this,

sample data,

```
> dput(head(outcome_split,3))
structure(list(AK = structure(list(hospital_name = c("ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER", 
"ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL", "BARTLETT REGIONAL HOSPITAL", "CENTRAL PENINSULA GENERAL HOSPITAL", 
"CORDOVA COMMUNITY MEDICAL CENTER", "FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "MT EDGECUMBE HOSPITAL", "NORTON SOUND REGIONAL HOSPITAL", 
"PEACEHEALTH KETCHIKAN MEDICAL             CENTER", "PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER", 
"PROVIDENCE KODIAK ISLAND MEDICAL CTR", "PROVIDENCE SEWARD HOSPITAL", 
"PROVIDENCE VALDEZ MEDICAL CENTER", "SITKA COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", 
"SOUTH PENINSULA HOSPITAL", "YUKON KUSKOKWIM DELTA REG HOSPITAL"
), state = c("AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK"), heart_attack = c(15.7, 
14.5, NA, NA, NA, 15.5, 17.7, NA, NA, NA, 13.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), heart_failure = c("11.6", "13.4", "11.6", "11.6", "Not Available", 
"15.6", "11.4", "Not Available", "Not Available", "11.4", "12.4", 
"Not Available", "Not Available", "Not Available", "Not Available", 
"10.8", "11.2"), pneumonia = c("15.5", "12.5", "11.6", "13.8", 
"Not Available", "13.4", "12.1", "14.2", "11.6", "11.3", "10.5", 
"12.0", "Not Available", "Not Available", "11.5", "12.2", "9.7"
), rank = c(4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("hospital_name", 
"state", "heart_attack", "heart_failure", "pneumonia", "rank"
), row.names = c(NA, -17L)), AL = structure(list(hospital_name = c("ANDALUSIA REGIONAL HOSPITAL", 
"ATHENS-LIMESTONE HOSPITAL", "ATMORE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER EAST", 
"BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH", "BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER-PRINCETON", 
"BIBB MEDICAL CENTER", "BIRMINGHAM VA MEDICAL CENTER", "BROOKWOOD MEDICAL CENTER", 
"BRYAN W WHITFIELD MEM HOSP INC", "BULLOCK COUNTY HOSPITAL", 
"CALLAHAN EYE FOUNDATION HOSPITAL", "CHEROKEE MEDICAL CENTER", 
"CHILTON MEDICAL CENTER", "CITIZENS BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER", 
"CLAY COUNTY HOSPITAL", "COMMUNITY HOSPITAL INC", "COOPER GREEN MERCY HOSPITAL", 
"COOSA VALLEY MEDICAL CENTER", "CRENSHAW COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", 
"CRESTWOOD MEDICAL CENTER", "CULLMAN REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"D C H REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"DALE MEDICAL CENTER", "DECATUR GENERAL HOSPITAL", "DEKALB REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"EAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER AND SNF", "ELBA GENERAL HOSPITAL", 
"ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "ELMORE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", 
"EVERGREEN MEDICAL CENTER", "FAYETTE MEDICAL CENTER", "FLORALA MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"FLOWERS HOSPITAL", "GADSDEN REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "GEORGE H. LANIER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"GEORGIANA HOSPITAL", "GREENE COUNTY HOSPITAL", "GROVE HILL MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"HALE COUNTY HOSPITAL", "HELEN KELLER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "HIGHLANDS MEDICAL CENTER", 
"HILL HOSPITAL OF SUMTER COUNTY", "HUNTSVILLE HOSPITAL", "INFIRMARY WEST", 
"J PAUL JONES HOSPITAL", "JACK HUGHSTON MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "JACKSON HOSPITAL & CLINIC INC", 
"JACKSON MEDICAL CENTER", "JACKSONVILLE MEDICAL CENTER", "L V STABLER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"LAKE MARTIN COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "LAKELAND COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", 
"LAWRENCE MEDICAL CENTER", "MARION REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER NORTH", "MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH", 
"MEDICAL CENTER BARBOUR", "MEDICAL CENTER ENTERPRISE", "MEDICAL WEST, AN AFFILIATE OF UAB HEALTH SYSTEM", 
"MIZELL MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "MOBILE INFIRMARY", "MONROE COUNTY HOSPITAL", 
"NORTH BALDWIN INFIRMARY", "NORTHEAST ALABAMA REGIONAL MED CENTER", 
"NORTHWEST MEDICAL CENTER", "PARKWAY MEDICAL CENTER", "PICKENS COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"PRATTVILLE BAPTIST HOSPITAL", "PROVIDENCE HOSPITAL", "RED BAY HOSPITAL", 
"RIVERVIEW REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "RUSSELL HOSPITAL", "RUSSELLVILLE HOSPITAL", 
"SHELBY BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER", "SHOALS HOSPITAL", "SOUTH BALDWIN REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER", "SPRINGHILL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"ST VINCENT'S BIRMINGHAM", "ST VINCENT'S EAST", "ST VINCENT'S ST CLAIR", 
"ST VINCENTS BLOUNT", "STRINGFELLOW MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "THOMAS HOSPITAL", 
"TRINITY MEDICAL CENTER", "TROY REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "TUSCALOOSA VA MEDICAL CENTER", 
"UNIV OF S AL CHILDREN'S & WOMEN'S HOS", "UNIV OF SOUTH ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER", 
"UNIVERSITY OF ALABAMA HOSPITAL", "VA CENTRAL ALABAMA HEALTHCARE SYSTEM - MONTGOMERY", 
"VAUGHAN REG MED CENTER PARKWAY CAMPUS", "WALKER BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER", 
"WASHINGTON COUNTY HOSPITAL", "WEDOWEE HOSPITAL", "WIREGRASS MEDICAL CENTER"
), state = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL"), heart_attack = c(NA, 15, NA, 14.2, 17.8, 14.9, NA, 
16.1, 16.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17.3, 16.7, 17.1, NA, 15.2, NA, 
13.3, 17.1, 15.8, 15.7, 17.3, 16.8, 18, 16.3, NA, 18.1, NA, NA, 
16.7, NA, 15.2, 16.7, 15.4, 14.5, NA, NA, NA, 19.6, 15, NA, 15.2, 
NA, NA, NA, 17.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.6, NA, NA, 18.5, NA, 
16.6, 15.3, NA, 19.3, NA, NA, 15.6, NA, 15.8, NA, 14.6, 15.2, 
NA, 16.9, 17.1, NA, 15.9, NA, 15.8, 14.3, 16, 16.2, 17.7, NA, 
NA, 16.4, 14.7, 16.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, NA, 14.7, 17, NA, NA, 
NA), heart_failure = c("10.1", "11.7", "10.8", "9.6", "11.8", 
"11.4", "14.0", "10.4", "13.5", "11.7", "12.3", "Not Available", 
"12.1", "11.5", "14.9", "12.6", "12.3", "Not Available", "11.7", 
"13.8", "13.8", "12.1", "11.2", "14.8", "11.8", "10.9", "16.6", 
"12.9", "Not Available", "11.3", "11.3", "9.1", "11.7", "10.4", 
"12.0", "10.7", "8.8", "10.8", "11.2", "10.4", "10.7", "12.6", 
"13.4", "Not Available", "12.4", "12.5", "Not Available", "10.8", 
"10.2", "12.3", "16.4", "11.1", "10.9", "13.6", "9.9", "11.5", 
"12.5", "15.2", "13.5", "12.9", "11.4", "13.6", "10.7", "13.0", 
"11.5", "11.2", "11.8", "10.5", "12.6", "14.8", "13.5", "12.6", 
"10.8", "11.6", "14.8", "13.6", "13.6", "15.1", "11.4", "10.4", 
"10.6", "10.9", "10.8", "13.0", "12.0", "12.8", "12.9", "11.2", 
"Not Available", "Not Available", "12.5", "12.5", "12.2", "12.0", 
"10.8", "Not Available", "10.4", "10.6"), pneumonia = c("11.1", 
"12.1", "13.0", "10.2", "14.3", "11.6", "13.6", "11.0", "13.0", 
"9.1", "12.1", "Not Available", "14.7", "11.2", "12.1", "11.8", 
"11.6", "Not Available", "11.4", "15.8", "10.4", "12.1", "11.3", 
"12.6", "9.9", "11.9", "15.8", "12.1", "12.0", "13.4", "11.2", 
"12.0", "12.9", "12.1", "11.3", "14.6", "10.3", "11.3", "11.5", 
"12.1", "11.5", "15.0", "12.9", "Not Available", "14.1", "13.1", 
"11.4", "10.9", "14.7", "9.3", "19.2", "13.0", "10.8", "10.7", 
"9.8", "10.0", "8.7", "13.9", "15.0", "12.9", "12.1", "14.9", 
"12.5", "15.6", "14.6", "13.2", "13.1", "11.9", "12.4", "14.2", 
"10.6", "11.6", "12.7", "14.9", "11.5", "10.7", "12.8", "9.8", 
"10.9", "13.8", "12.6", "16.2", "11.4", "15.3", "12.0", "13.1", 
"13.9", "11.1", "Not Available", "Not Available", "Not Available", 
"12.7", "11.3", "14.0", "11.9", "Not Available", "13.9", "12.3"
), rank = c(52L, 9L, 53L, 2L, 46L, 8L, 54L, 26L, 30L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 42L, 32L, 39L, 60L, 12L, 61L, 1L, 40L, 21L, 20L, 
43L, 35L, 47L, 28L, 62L, 48L, 63L, 64L, 33L, 65L, 13L, 34L, 17L, 
4L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 51L, 10L, 69L, 14L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 44L, 73L, 
74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 18L, 78L, 79L, 49L, 80L, 31L, 16L, 81L, 50L, 
82L, 83L, 19L, 84L, 22L, 85L, 5L, 15L, 86L, 37L, 41L, 87L, 24L, 
88L, 23L, 3L, 25L, 27L, 45L, 89L, 90L, 29L, 6L, 36L, 91L, 92L, 
93L, 94L, 11L, 95L, 7L, 38L, 96L, 97L, 98L)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("hospital_name", 
"state", "heart_attack", "heart_failure", "pneumonia", "rank"
), row.names = c(NA, -98L)), AR = structure(list(hospital_name = c("ARKANSAS CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL", 
"ARKANSAS HEART HOSPITAL", "ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER", 
"ARKANSAS SURGICAL HOSPITAL", "ASHLEY COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"BAPTIST HEALTH MEDICAL CENTER HEBER SPINGS", "BAPTIST HEALTH MEDICAL CENTER NORTH LITTLE ROCK", 
"BAPTIST HEALTH MEDICAL CENTER-LITTLE ROCK", "BAPTIST HEALTH MEDICAL CENTER-STUTTGART", 
"BAPTIST HEALTH MEDICSL CENTER-ARKADELPHIA", "BAXTER REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"BOONEVILLE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "BRADLEY COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"CHICOT MEMORIAL MEDICAL CENTER", "COMMUNITY MEDICAL CENTER IZARD COUNTY", 
"CONWAY REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "CRITTENDEN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"CROSSRIDGE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "DALLAS COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"DE QUEEN MEDICAL CENTER, INC", "DELTA MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "DEWITT HOSPITAL & NURSING HOME, INC", 
"DREW MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "EUREKA SPRINGS HOSPITAL, LLC", "FAYETTEVILLE AR VA MEDICAL CENTER", 
"FIVE RIVERS MEDICAL CENTER", "FORREST CITY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"GREAT RIVER MEDICAL CENTER", "HARRIS HOSPITAL", "HELENA REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"HOT SPRING COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER", "HOWARD MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"JEFFERSON REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "JOHN ED CHAMBERS MEM HOSP, INC", 
"JOHNSON REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "LAWRENCE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"LEO N LEVI NATIONAL ARTHRITIS HOSPITAL", "LITTLE RIVER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"MAGNOLIA HOSPITAL", "MCGEHEE HOSPITAL", "MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH ARKANSAS", 
"MEDICAL PARK HOSPITAL", "MENA REGIONAL HEALTH SYSTEM", "MERCY HOSPITAL SCOTT COUNTY", 
"MERCY HOSPITAL TURNER MEMORIAL", "MERCY MEDICAL CENTER", "NATIONAL PARK MEDICAL CENTER", 
"NEA BAPTIST MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "NORTH ARKANSAS REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"NORTH LOGAN MERCY HOSPITAL", "NORTH METRO MEDICAL CENTER", "NW ARKANSAS HOSPITALS, LLC", 
"OUACHITA COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER", "OZARK HEALTH", "OZARKS COMMUNITY HOSPITAL OF GRAVETTE", 
"PHYSICIANS' SPECIALTY HOSPITAL", "PIGGOTT COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", 
"RIVER VALLEY MEDICAL CENTER", "SALINE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "SILOAM SPRINGS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"SOUTH MISSISSISSPI COUNTY REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "SPARKS REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", 
"ST BERNARDS MEDICAL CTR", "ST EDWARD MERCY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"ST JOHN'S HOSPITAL-BERRYVILLE", "ST JOSEPHS MERCY HEALTH CENTER INC", 
"ST MARYS REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "ST VINCENT INFIRMARY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"ST VINCENT MEDICAL CENTER/NORTH", "ST VINCENT MORRILTON", "STONE COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"SUMMIT MEDICAL CENTER", "UAMS MEDICAL CENTER", "VA CENTRAL AR. VETERANS HEALTHCARE SYSTEM LR", 
"WASHINGTON REGIONAL MED CTR AT NORTH HILLS", "WHITE COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER", 
"WHITE RIVER MEDICAL CENTER"), state = c("AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR"), heart_attack = c(NA, 
11.9, 17.1, NA, NA, NA, 14.4, 14.7, 15.7, NA, 16.4, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 18.9, 14.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17.1, NA, NA, NA, 
17.3, NA, 15.8, NA, 16.8, 17.3, 16.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21.9, 
17.3, NA, NA, NA, 14.8, 19.1, 14.5, 17.2, NA, 17.1, 17.3, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.7, 15.6, NA, 16.7, 17.7, 14.9, NA, 17.4, 
18.8, 16.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.5, 14.5, 15.2, 17.5, 17.6), heart_failure = c("Not Available", 
"13.3", "14.4", "Not Available", "13.1", "11.5", "13.3", "11.1", 
"11.0", "11.7", "14.7", "15.7", "12.6", "12.3", "14.8", "15.6", 
"10.9", "11.0", "12.1", "13.2", "12.6", "12.5", "12.9", "13.7", 
"10.2", "14.0", "12.8", "14.2", "11.3", "12.1", "14.4", "11.9", 
"13.2", "10.0", "11.8", "10.9", "Not Available", "10.7", "14.9", 
"12.8", "13.6", "12.7", "13.5", "12.5", "Not Available", "13.0", 
"13.5", "17.2", "11.2", "13.8", "9.6", "11.9", "12.5", "12.4", 
"Not Available", "Not Available", "11.6", "11.9", "14.4", "11.8", 
"12.0", "14.0", "14.6", "12.6", "11.7", "14.3", "13.1", "12.8", 
"12.6", "13.2", "12.1", "14.0", "12.1", "9.0", "13.9", "13.7", 
"12.5"), pneumonia = c("Not Available", "10.4", "11.7", "Not Available", 
"14.3", "12.0", "10.2", "11.0", "14.2", "12.6", "16.1", "12.8", 
"12.7", "14.0", "12.3", "14.9", "12.6", "11.2", "15.7", "11.6", 
"11.7", "13.0", "13.5", "13.7", "16.9", "11.4", "15.3", "15.2", 
"12.1", "13.3", "11.5", "16.7", "11.0", "12.1", "13.8", "12.4", 
"Not Available", "12.3", "12.8", "15.3", "14.6", "15.1", "13.3", 
"13.8", "13.0", "13.4", "13.3", "11.3", "11.8", "11.6", "13.4", 
"11.5", "12.4", "13.4", "12.0", "Not Available", "11.3", "17.9", 
"12.2", "13.8", "10.8", "12.2", "13.3", "12.8", "12.4", "11.3", 
"15.4", "12.0", "11.1", "15.2", "9.9", "12.8", "12.6", "12.1", 
"13.4", "12.5", "12.1"), rank = c(36L, 1L, 20L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
2L, 6L, 11L, 40L, 14L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 33L, 3L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 21L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 24L, 55L, 13L, 56L, 
17L, 25L, 18L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 35L, 26L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
7L, 34L, 4L, 23L, 65L, 22L, 27L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
12L, 10L, 72L, 16L, 31L, 8L, 73L, 28L, 32L, 19L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 15L, 5L, 9L, 29L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("hospital_name", 
"state", "heart_attack", "heart_failure", "pneumonia", "rank"
), row.names = c(NA, -77L))), .Names = c("AK", "AL", "AR"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not to filter, you just want to change a column based on another column I suppose. So you could simply use `mutate` with `ifelse`

```
df[[i]] %>% 
  mutate(hospital_name = ifelse(rank == num, hospital_name, NA)) %>% 
  select(hospital_name, state)
```

Edit: Per state, you could get your results first. Then convert to a factor (if it isn't already) and then fill missing factors with `NA`. E.g.

```
df[[3]] %>% filter(rank == 20) %>% select(hospital_name, state) %>%
  mutate(state = factor(state, levels = state.abb)) %>%
  complete(state, fill = list(hospital_name = NA))
```

If you join from multiple lists, of course you should do factor conversion + `complete` in the final step

```
# A tibble: 50 x 2
   state hospital_name                    
   <fct> <chr>                            
 1 AL    NA                               
 2 AK    NA                               
 3 AZ    NA                               
 4 AR    ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER
 5 CA    NA                               
 6 CO    NA                               
 7 CT    NA  
....
```

**Edit2:**

So, from looking at the function on RPubs, I wrote the part related to your question as follows:

```
rankall <- function(data, outcome, num = "best") {
  outcome_split <- data

  output <- do.call(
    rbind, lapply(outcome_split, function(x) {
    x <- x[order(x$hospital_name), ]
    x <- x %>% mutate(rank = rank(x[, outcome], ties.method = "first"))
    x %>% filter(rank == num) %>% select(hospital_name, state)
    })
  )

  output <- output %>% mutate(state = factor(state, levels = state.abb)) %>%
    complete(state, fill = list(hospital_name = NA))

  return(output)
}
```

I replaced the for-loop with `lapply` and `rbind` the result directly. **Then**, after we obtain the results for the states where the filter is present, we fill in the missing states with `NA`.

Then,

```
rankall(df, "rank", 20)
```

where `df` is your data from this question, yields

```
# A tibble: 50 x 2
   state hospital_name                    
   <fct> <chr>                            
 1 AL    D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL   
 2 AK    NA                               
 3 AZ    NA                               
 4 AR    ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER
 5 CA    NA                               
 6 CO    NA                               
 7 CT    NA                               
 8 DE    NA                               
 9 FL    NA                               
10 GA    NA                               
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Please note that you don't really have to split your data here.

Again, using the data from your question as `df`,

```
full <- do.call(rbind, df)
```

This is, I assume, the shape of your data before you split it. Then, using only `dplyr`,

```
num = 20
full %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  filter(rank == num) %>% 
  slice(1:1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(hospital_name, state) %>%
  mutate(state = factor(state, levels = state.abb)) %>%
  complete(state, fill = list(hospital_name = NA))
```

Will give me exactly the same result.

Comment: I have a function where I would pass outcome and rank(num), that function would return a hospital name per state. If I do this then where there is a mismatch (data frame in a list ) all the rows are getting changed to NA. I only want result as NA for AK state

`>  outcome_split[[1]] %>% mutate(hospital_name=ifelse(rank == 20, hospital_name, NA)) %>% select(hospital_name, state)`

Comment: The list has about 50 data frames for about each state, I would extract per state one hospital name and collapse that extracted list into a data frame using `do.call` and print the results as above. But when I do mutate as adviced by you, I get all the rows from the data frame where hospital name has been changed to NA for every row.

Comment: So per rank there will always be max 1 hospital per state, or how do you select it ?

Comment: yes, I ordered the hospital_names first and then created rank column `outcome_split[[i]] <- outcome_split[[i]] %>% mutate(rank = rank(outcome_split[[i]][,outcome], ties.method="first"))` so rank is unique, if there is a outcome of same value then as I had ordered the hospital name initially, the hospital with lower alphabet will be ranked first and then the next hospital.

Comment: thank you but the following issues,
1. The first data frame of the list does not have any matching values at all, I am not sure how the complete function works but I am getting the following error,
`> outcome_split[[1]] %>% filter(rank == 20) %>% select(hospital_name, state) %>% mutate(state = factor(state, levels = state.abb)) %>% complete(state, fill = list(hospital_name = NA))
Error in UseMethod("left_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Comment: 2. This query gives me a tibble for every element of a list `outcome_split[[i]]` and I would like to explain what I would be doing next - I would saving the matched results in a new list and using ` output <- do.call(rbind, outcome_rank_filter)` i.e., collapse the list of data frames into one data frame and return that data frame.

Comment: The query you suggested returns an NA for every state as in the below output -
`> outcome_split[[2]] %>% filter(rank == 20) %>% select(hospital_name, state) %>% mutate(state = factor(state, levels = state.abb)) %>% complete(state, fill = list(hospital_name = NA))
# A tibble: 50 x 2
    state                  hospital_name
   <fctr>                          <chr>
 1     AL D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
 2     AK                           <NA>
 3     AZ                           <NA>
 4     AR                           <NA>`

Comment: but when I save this in a loop into `outcome_split[[i]]` and collapse it into a dataframe using do.call I would get all the NA from across all tibbles into one. But I am only interested in getting NA value for the state, which does not have a matching rank.
You can look at my full code if you would like to understand how I am trying to flow here, https://rpubs.com/shafeeqrahaman/370388 and `else if(is.numeric(num)) #Check if num is numeric` this part is specific where I am trying to run and get this result.

Comment: The output I am looking for is attached to the last part of the question, I apologize for the series of posts but I am trying to see if I can explain in a much better way so as you can help me learn and achieve the required output.

Comment: Please see my second edit - also, I would suggest loading the data outside of the function!

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation, the way you showed looks so simple and informative. I really appreciate it, had not you provided in such a detailed manner I wouldn't have been able to understand.